# Long query for testing

Tags: mysql, crash, fault-tolerance

I'm trying some fault-tolerance and in aplication and does anyone know of a long executing query using the default mysql tables?

The idea is to run that query, crash the mysqld to see if my app detects the error and tries to connect to another mysqld.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Even the longest query will not crash the mysqld! you might lose the connection, depending on the driver you are using, but I believe the server will run and run and run until it is finished.
And long running queries will be hard to do with the standard tables. In my experience, altering indexes on very big (10's ir better 100's of millions of rows, depending on the spedd/ram of your server) will keep it busy for quite a while

Comment: I don't think the OP wants the query to crash mysqld. I think s/he wants to do that separately.  The OP just wants to be sure that a query is running.

Comment: in that case, the sentence "The idea is to run that query, crash the mysqld to see if my app detects the error and tries to connect to another mysqld." is a bit confusing :). Anyway, the other answers probably got it better than I did anyway

Answer (score 0):

Just do multiple cross joins and save into a table:

```
create table dum as
    select *
    from information_schema.tables t cross join
         information_schema.tables t cross join
         information_schema.tables t cross join
         information_schema.tables t cross join
         information_schema.tables t cross join
         information_schema.tables t cross join
         information_schema.tables t cross join
         information_schema.tables t;
```

Or if you don't want to create a table, maybe something like this:

```
    select count(*)
    from information_schema.tables t cross join
         information_schema.tables t cross join
         information_schema.tables t cross join
         information_schema.tables t cross join
         information_schema.tables t cross join
         information_schema.tables t cross join
         information_schema.tables t cross join
         information_schema.tables t;
```

I just realized -- I don't know if `information_schema.tables` actually has any rows in a new installation.  But you get the idea.  The worst case would be putting together something like:

```
select count(*)
from (select 1 as n union all select 2 as n union all select 3 as n union all select 4 as n) n1 cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 as n union all select 3 as n union all select 4 as n) n2 cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 as n union all select 3 as n union all select 4 as n) n3 cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 as n union all select 3 as n union all select 4 as n) n4 cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 as n union all select 3 as n union all select 4 as n) n5 cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 as n union all select 3 as n union all select 4 as n) n6 cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 as n union all select 3 as n union all select 4 as n) n7 cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 as n union all select 3 as n union all select 4 as n) n8 cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 as n union all select 3 as n union all select 4 as n) n9;
```

By the way, this is a fun question.  So much of my life is devoted to getting queries to run faster, that it is amusing to think about the opposite problem.

Answer (score 0):

The [`SLEEP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_sleep) function might help you. `SELECT SLEEP(10);` returns `0` after 10 seconds.